# How do I get rid of the uncheck conversion warning as a result of using PropertiesConfiguration from apache.commons

Tags: apache-commons, suppress-warnings

I prefer not to use SuppressWarnings.  I prefer to write code that produces no complaints.  I import the apache.commons class PropertiesConfiguration.

This file was created with a text editor:

```
numbers = 0.222,0.333
animals = dog,cat
```

I then read the file into an instance of PropertiesConfiguration, say it is referenced by "pc".

```
                List<String> myStringList = pc.getList("animals");
```

The call to getList() produces a compile-time warning about unchecked conversions.  How do I improve this without SupressWarnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `getList()` returns a generic `List` object.  How about using `getStringArray()` instead which returns an array of `String`s?